# How can I use session variables in a report created with the Forena module?

Tags: 7, log-messages, forena

I've installed [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena). It's basically working, but I have some questions (see bottom of post to get right to it).

#### What I want to accomplish is the following

I want an anonymous user of the module page to be able to export their recommendations as a CSV file with a link like 'download now' or something.

Here's the staging environment for the tool I'm talking about, so you can see how it works: http://staging.grantstation-pathfinder.com/pathfinder.

#### So, as you can see, here's what I have so far

I have a custom module that's a multi-step form. The module prints out each page of the form. The user selects one option on each page (3 pages total) and on the final page submits the form. The module then redirects the user to a 'recommendations' page (page 4 - modulename/recommendations) where some custom SQL prints out to the page recommended resources for that user based on their selections in the form.

The values the users select are saved in session variables.

Here's how those variables get stored as sessions in the form itself. (This is the second page of the form, but they are all basically the same.)

```
function pathfindertool_first_form($form, $form_state) {
 // .. some code, some other fields, directions, etc.
        '#default_value' => isset($values['role']) ? $values['role'] : NULL,
        '#options' => array(
        t('Grant Writer'),
        t('Nonprofit Administrator'),
        t('Nonprofit Founder'),
        t('Consultant'))
    );
      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Next'),
      );
      return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Submit handler for the first form.
     *
     * @see pathfindertool_first_form() above
     */
     function pathfindertool_first_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      $values = $form_state['values'];

      // Save values to the form storage, add the next step function callback
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; 
      $form_state['storage']['role'] = $values['role'];
      // submit code
    }
```

On the recommendations page I call SQL and use the session variables to determine which recommendations to display to users.

Here's how I set the session variables and redirect the users to the recommendation's page.

```
$form_state['storage']['topic'] = $values['topic'];
// set session variables to be used on recommendations page
$_SESSION['role'] = $form_state['storage']['role'];
$_SESSION['level'] = $form_state['storage']['level'];
$_SESSION['topic'] = $form_state['storage']['topic'];
// when user clicks 'submit' redirect them to recommendations page
$form_state['redirect'] = 'pathfinder/recommendations';
```

I successfully installed and configured the Forena module, and it displays my tabular data from the SQL file I created with the parameters I manually set. The CSV download works too. That's all fine.

How do I ensure the Forena modules uses the session variables set by the user in the multi-page form (and not my predefined parameters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not (yet) sure about this one, because of the "*session variables*" that aren't clear enough to me (yet) ... Below are a few techniques (features) that you may want to consider to get it to work.

## 1. Using JavaScript and/or Skins

A possible solution "might" be to think of some technique you can implement via a JavaScript. And then make that JavaScript available via what in Forena is called "[skins](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/help.skins#javascript)" (used for e.g. *theming* a report, like to enable the 'DataTables' plugin if you want, etc).

There are some "interesting" issues in the Forena issue queue with some great examples (ideas) of things you can do (add to Forena) via JavaScripts and/or Skins. HEre are a few of them:

- [Using the dataTables plugin to format reports](https://www.drupal.org/node/2478589), via an appropriate "skin".
- [Making table headers sticky](https://www.drupal.org/node/1768634), note the comments [nr 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/1768634#comment-6588862) (using Drupal Behaviours) and [nr 10](https://www.drupal.org/node/1768634#comment-6593268) (adding some JavaScript library).

## 2. Specifying Report Parameters as part of the URL

*Report Parameters* are similar to using *arguments* in Views. You can specify them as part of the URL, by first adding a `?`-mark, followed by the name of the report parameter, a `=`-sign, and then the parameter value. So something like `?state=VA` that you append to the report URL.

To see it at work in the demo site, try [this example](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.user_distribution_simple?state=VA) which uses `?state=VA` (watch the URL of it also). Then change the end of the URL to something like `?state=IL`,  `?state=CA`, etc. To be complete, you can also specify multiple parameters (+their values) in an URL.

So if you have a way to massage those session variables in a such string added to the URL, then the answer to your question is something like "*pass them as report parameters via the URL*".

## 3. Other approaches

If what is above won't work, then please add more details about those "session variabes" (so that I can refine/rework my answer accordingly).

And if we don't find a real answer, then its time to experience the "support" that comes with Forena, via its issue queue on D.O. ... After all, keep in mind that I'm only a co-maintainer of this module. When I'm stuck (or out of Forena-inspiration), I escalate such questions/issues to David (the module owner and creator or Forena).

Comment: thank you again. I might have to go that route. But before I do, I thought I'd give you that extra info. you requested. I edited my question above and added what I believe is the relevant code for setting the session variables. This code is all in the .module file and occurs BEFORE the user gets redirected to the recommendations page. Actually the last line of the 2nd code chunk above SENDS them to the recommendation page. But you can see how the session vars are set.

Comment: ah, ok. My understanding is that session vars are stored on the server. Where is determined by the session.save_path configuration. Usually this is in /tmp. This is totally just a php thing and doesn't touch the database I don't believe. It seems like if we used forena we'd have to make users include their parameters manually, which isn't ideal in this situation since they've already defined their parameters once when they took the multi-page form. Unless there's a way for forena to read from the /tmp directory?

Comment: yes, very interesting! let me play around with this and I'll get back to you when I have a chance (probably tomorrow) to experiment with this. It's promising though.

Comment: ok, great, "your turn" again ... looks like we're coming close to answer ALL 3 (original) questions ... While reviewing this parms stuff, make sure to also digest the docu that comes with Forena related to "parameters". And if you can/want, consider creating a docu issue in the forena issue queue about missing pieces in the docu (like how to use them in URLs, as I detailed in my answer) ... Better still: submit a forena patch to enhance the relevant docu (you'd learn a lot about how to use Forena for creating HELP documentation also ... As I did when I started with it).

Comment: Just curious if you made any progress on "playing" (without trying to rush you) ... PS: did you change your "user name"?

Comment: Ok, closing the loop on this bad boy. So I was able to get it working finally! It was actually pretty easy once I sat down and did it (after reading about parameters). The videos helped a lot. Once I'd created my sql with params and loaded it into forena reports, I just added this link to my recommendations page to take the user-generated variables and plop them into the URL. Now when a user clicks the link the link itself just passes those variables using php as parameters in the URL to the report link. Simple!

Comment: Great to hear, and Merci for the accept ... While I have upu online-on-the-line, what about tat oter question about http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165488 ? Ie wuould you be interested in reconsidering usiing forena for that also? If so I'd be happy to suggest an answer there also ...

Comment: sure, that would be great. Keep in mind that's using a Views-based search with exposed keyterms and drop down filters for users.

Comment: yes I changed my username ;)

Comment: ok I was finally able to submit an issue/patch to the Forena ticket queue. That's my first one so I hope I did it right.

Comment: I assume it's issue nr 2554473 . It's status is a bit bizarre: patch - to be ported,, but there is no patch attached. Am I missing something?

Comment: woops - ok I think I updated it now..

Comment: Looks a bit clearer already. Extra suggestion: how about you EDIT the appropriate Help pages (in FRX fmt ...), and submit the changes as a patch attached to that same issue also? I'm sure David (the module owner) would happily review / correct / integrate it then ... That's how all "my" contributed docu got included also ...

Comment: gladly but I don't have an account with the FRX docu site. Know how to get one?

Comment: You don't need one, I don't have one either ... Just do like so: (1) edit "your own version of any FRX file (or create new ones)" (2) Create a patch from it (3) attach the patch to an issue in the issue queue. Either David (module owner) or i (co-maintainer) will then review the patch, provide feedback, etc. And if everything goes well, some day "your" patch gets included in the DEV version (with attribution to you ...). Makes sense?

Comment: I think so. So basically just copy the section of the FRX file to add to, write my bit, and put that in the issue I already created. Sound about right?

Comment: Indeed, and like I wrote preferably in patch format. But if you want/can, also add the entire (updated) frx file. That may be used by other reviewers who who like to do so, or by people not familiar with patches.