# How to format database fields in a report created with Forena?

Tags: 7, log-messages, forena

How can I choose how to display the fields from the database returned by the data block (using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module)? Such as a field just returns a number, but each number of that field represents something else that I'd like to display. For example:

```
 if (id=5) { $text = "see website"; } else { $text = "free"; }
```

If this is not possible, how in general can I change how the fields are displayed?

Comment: For the background of this question, see  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165512/reportwriting-questions-about-the-forena-reports-module.

Comment: This question was 1 out of 3 questions contained in the **original version** of the question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165512 (refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/165512/1 for more details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're "developing" a report (= Specifying the various report options), you have a choice to do so using either of the following features:

- Use the [WYSIWYG Report Writer](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg), something *novice* Forena users typically do, or *end users* that are granted permissions to "develop" their own reports (and which get saved in Forena's typical '.frx' files).

  In this case, you should look at [Fields (within the WYSIWYG tutorial)](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg#fields), located also at `/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg#fields` in your own site.
- "Code" your own reports in the XHTML language used in Forena (saved in '.frx' files), which is called "[FRX Report Writing](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingfrx)". This is what the real power users will want to do, since it gives them the full XHTML power to build any report.

  In this case, you should look at [Fields (within the FRX tutorial)](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingfrx#fields), located at `/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg#fields` in your own site.

Be prepared: there are quite some options to pick from ...

Comment: I've updated the structure > forena reports > rec report > layout page. I removed two <th> rows as well as two matching <td> rows. I then updated it. I cleared the cache (drupal and browser) but when I download the CSV it still shows the fields I thought I'd removed. 

When I go to view the data returned in the structure > forena reports area it's showing only the correct fields. 

Know how to update the CSV so it returns only the desired fields as well?