# How to adjust price in Drupal Commerce based on quantity and attributes?

Tags: 7, commerce

I wonder how I can adjust the price in Drupal Commerce depending on quantity and attributes.

I found *[Commerce Price Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table)* and *[Commerce Pricelist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist)* for **quantity**, and *[Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes)* for **attributes**. Not sure which one is more matchable for that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Attributes

Consider using the [Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides some enhancements to the Commerce Product Option and Commerce Product Attributes handling by applying pricing rules to custom product attributes.
>
> Features:
>
> - Dynamic price calculation based on selected operators.
> - Cart combination based on product attributes.
> - Support for multi currency.
> - Multilingual attributes.
> - Different attributes and settings per product.
> - Price adjustments either per item or per order.
> - Rules integration.
> - Easy UI for editing and reordering attributes.

This module depends on [Commerce Product Option](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option) and [Commerce Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes).

Refer to [the video about this module](https://vimeo.com/59862366) for a great introduction about it.

## Quantity

From your question it's not realy clear to me what exactly you mean the quantity part of it.

Which is also why I'm not convinced (yet) that you should use the modules
[Commerce Price Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table) or [Commerce Pricelist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist).

However, you should probably consider the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, using some custom Rules, something like so:

- Events = Calculate Sell Price of Product.
- Actions = calculate the price, and set the price to the calculated value.

Not sure (yet) ifff you'd need some extra 'Conditions' added to this.

Refer to [Drupal commerce and rules: changing the product price dynamically](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/drupal-commerce-and-rules-changing-product-price-dynamically) for an example of dynamically changing product prices.

Comment: Yeah, it is a confusing question, sorry. I tried to combined two questions in a single one.
Since, I finally figured out with Attributes, I only need to understand how quantity/price modules work (i mean, which one I need). For example, if people want 1-5 pictures, the price is $49/each, if 6-10, than it is going to be $39 per each.
I found Commerce Price Table (1st) and Commerce Pricelist (2nd) modules for that. Looks like 2nd is more functional, but it is very "new" ... Or some other modules are also popular for that? Or I can do it right from Commerce?

Comment: aha, I'm glad to read that you confirm my initial perception about this question also (that they are actually 2 questions). If you don't want to take the risk that it gets put on hold (as what happened recently with the question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165512 ...), I'd suggest you MOVE the quantity/price part of it to a NEW question. I'd then be happy to also move my related part in my answer to there, and enhance it then with some other related suggestions to help you decide on that 'new' question (possibly with other modules also). If you agree, let me know, ok?

Comment: Definitely agree :) Created.